# Trying to parse json data without having access to OPEN_JSON

Tags: sql-server

We have a production database that has compatibility level of 100, this cannot change and open_json requires a level of 130. So I'm trying to figure out a little work around

Here is an example json

```sql
SET @json = '{
    "sessionid": "XXXXX",
    "userid": "XXXX",
    "scorm": [{
            "name": "variable_name",
            "value": "variable_value"
        },
        {
            "name": "variable_name",
            "value": "variable_value"
        },
        ... Continues on like this
    ]
}';
```

So I am able to get values out of this JSON by doing the following

```sql
SELECT JSON(@json,'$.sessionid') as SESSIONID
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.scorm[0].value') as FirstValue
```

But I have no idea how many will be inside the scorm: [{}] array, but we need all of them to save into a table. MAX there ever will be is probably 25 different values.

Soo I figured I could do something like:

```sql
//PSUEDO CODE

while(value != null)
DO
  //Get values
  select value = JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.scorm[0].value') as VALUE
  select name = JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.scorm[0].name') as NAME

  //Erase values from json
  SET @json = JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.scorm[0], NULL)
  SET @json = REPLACE(@json,'null,','');
  
  //Insert into table
  Insert (name,value) into TABLE
```

This is essentially getting the topmost value from the json array, and then setting it to 'NULL' and manipulating the string to get rid of it. Meaning now the json array has a new topmost value.

Then I would continue on like this and insert data into my table for each name/value.

This all seems like a *terrible* way to be doing it, and I can't imagine this is good, nor fast.

Am I missing something obvious? Some other-way I could be doing this (without access to OPEN_JSON()) ?

Comment: T-SQL is awful at string manipulation. There *are* solutions out there that best attempt to parse JSON using native T-SQL (a Google/Bing/DuckDuckGo/etc will find you these), however, you're best off with a CLR function or doing the parsing outside of SQL Server entirely if you don't have access to the JSON functionality introduced in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: `USE master` should let you use `OPENJSON`

Comment: Or you could hard-code 25 `JSON_VALUE` paths, it will just return NULL on ones that don't exist. Which version of SQL Server do you have? If you are on 2017+ then you can join a tally table and get the path dynamically.

Comment: @charlieface it is 2016, and I unfortunately cant hardcode the values.

Comment: @Charlieface would I be able to switch to master, create a temp table and fill out the rows from the json data, then switch back to the main database and assign the temp table?..... That might work hmmmm

Comment: Out of interest, what is the reason you need to stay in SQL Server 2008 compatibility? 2008 itself hasn't been supported for almost 2 years now, so still having an datanase at that level is only going to become problematic; especially at your next upgrade as level 100 (and possibly even 110) won't be available in the next SQL Server release.

Comment: @larnu what potential risks are associated with upgrading a production database from level 100 -> level 130?

Comment: What do you mean by a risk? Breaking changes? Those are still documented, even 2012's, if you're after those. You'll be using the new cardinality estimator too, but there's plenty of articles out there about that.

Comment: Why not hard-code, I mean `JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.scorm[0].name'), JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.scorm[1].name'), JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.scorm[2].name')...`